# Can "oa" be used as a substitute for "o"?

Tags: conjunciones

Google translate the other day decided that "oa" was an alternate form of "o" translating from English. Is "oa" valid?

Comment: Some more context would be fine, but I can already tell you that "oa" does not exist.

Comment: Phil: welcome to [spanish.se]. We'd like to help you, but to do so we first need you to take into account that we need details. As @Paco said, please provide more context. You can get ideas on how good answers are asked by reading [ask].

Comment: Do you mean to say that when Google Translate says "June bugs" is "errores de junio" in Spanish, there might be some bugs in Google?

Answer (score 1):

*oa* is not an Spanish word.
It seems that oa is the name of a game in Honduras but it's not used anywhere else, and it doesn't have anything to do with *o*.
I guess it's a typo.

Comment: I suspect that it's an artifact of Google's new neural net processing system that has been the buzz for the past couple of months.  Google's "Translate" generally does an often eerily good translation.  I have been totally amazed on many occasions, but there are glitches inherent in the structure of the neural net.

Comment: Whatever the system starts with in a given area - say "home security" - tends to become locked in by the training loop, errors and all. So, Translate changed "security" to "home security" in one instance, even when nothing in the original directly implied it, an error that would not have happened with the old "Translate" that ran off data bases and algorythms.

Comment: So, somehow the system made an association between some input that probably had no direct relevance and concluded that "oa" was the right way to translate "or."  Thanks for verifying that "oa" is totally wrong. Now it's in Google's court.  Oh, and it was definitely not a "typo." So, a new form of error to watch out for...

Comment: I mean that typo (from texts) has been assimilated into the database of right translations.

Comment: I have to say that I absolutely disagree with the idea of google translations being good. A large majority of the google translations to Spanish are full of mistakes of all types, and as a native spanish speaker my eyes hurts every time I read one of those. It should be used **ONLY** to try to understand the overall meaning, never as a way to learn how to write or speak Spanish.